# Emberjs subfolder model fetching

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have multiple endpoints for fetching clients.

In my '/clients' page I want to use 'clients/clients' path to fetch clients
I have a subfolder "clients" in my models folder and model client.js in it.
I also have usual client.js model in models folder, but it is used for another endpoint.

So the question is: When I do

```
this.store.findAll('clients/client')
```

It fetches clients from 'clients/clients' endpoint but doesn't use model "clients.js" for 'clients' subfolder. How can I specify what model ember should use?

Answer (score 0):

Models are not nested. If you really want to use different models use different model names. But probably you can use the same model and just want to fetch it differently or use a relationship. If you provide more context may we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You can use model names as follows: `user.js, user-profile.js, user-status.js`